# Typescript lookup from object literal

Tags: typescript, lookup, object-literal

I have an object literal like this in Typescript:

```
const data={
  a:'valueOfA',
  b:'valueOfB,
  ...
}
```

Then I need to update values in different places by passing the object and the property to update like this:

```
function update(obj,prop){
...
}
update(data,'a');
```

This of course works, but I'd like to access the property using dot notation and taking advantage of intellisense in the IDE. So I can call the function like this:

```
update(data,KeysOfData.a);
```

I did a first implementation that works well and provides intellisense but it looks pretty ugly to me and I'd like to know if there are better ways to obtain the result. Here's the current implementation:

```
type FormProps = {
    firstName?: string,
    lastName?: string,
    email?: string
}

const formData: FormProps = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: ''
}

type FormItemName = keyof FormProps;
type FormItem = {
    [key in FormItemName]: string
}

// Generates lookup object
const Fields: FormItem = Object.keys(formData).reduce<FormItem>((obj, field) => {
    obj[field as FormItemName] = field;
    return obj;
}, {} as any);


// Later call to update
update(formData,Fields.firstName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll treat this question as one asking how to use generics and `keyof` to make your code reusable and improve type safety.

---

### First suggestion: Your solution, but using generics

You can extract your implementation so you can reuse it for other objects like so:

```js
// Generic reusable lookup type
type FieldLookup<T> = { [key in keyof T]: string }

// Generic reusable lookup generation function
function generateFieldLookup<T>(data: T): FieldLookup<T> {
    return Object.keys(formData).reduce((obj, field) => {
        obj[field as keyof T] = field;
        return obj;
    }, {} as FieldLookup<T>)
}

// Generates lookup object
const Fields = generateFieldLookup(formData)


// Later call to update
update(formData, Fields.firstName);
```

However, what this type says is that a property of T is also a property of the lookup object that has some string as its value, a more correct type would be:

```js
type FieldLookup<T> = { [key in keyof T]: key; }

function generateFieldLookup<T>(data: T): FieldLookup<T> {
    return Object.keys(formData).reduce((obj, field) => {
        const key = field as keyof T;
        obj[key] = key;
        return obj;
    }, {} as FieldLookup<T>)
}
```

Now when you hover over `Fields.firstName` you'll also get its exact value of the type. However, it will say that `undefined` is a possibility. That's because nowhere in the type does it say that all fields are included in the lookup.

If this cases a problem for you anywhere in the code just do `Fields.firstName!`

---

### Second suggestion: Type `update`

If you can sacrifice the ability for the IDE to give you suggestions when you click the dot, and just want type safety and suggestions via hovering over the function to get the inferred type, you can do away with this whole implementation and just type update as:

```js
function update<T>(obj: T, prop: keyof T): void


// Later call to update
update(formData, 'firstName');
```

Note that this suggestion does note exclude the one before, you can use both.

If you do, you'll have to use the *more advanced* version of the implementation in the first suggestion, with the exclamation mark, i.e. do:

```js
// Generic reusable lookup type
type FieldLookup<T> = { [key in keyof T]: key }

function update<T>(obj: T, prop: keyof T): void

// Later call to update
update(formData, Fields.firstName!);
```

Comment: Great answer and very well documented thanks! My question was more about finding a way to avoid the lookup object generator and looks like I can't skip it.
Anyway, using the bang operator here might be a nice solution to cleanup a little bit. Keeping the question open to check other opinions.

Comment: As I've mentioned, you can skip it if you are willing give up on having the dot suggestions  and can retype update, which will give you the same type safety, just not the desired suggestion mechanism. If you want the dot suggestion mechanism then you need an object to call a dot on, and there is no built in JS mechanism that can give you that right out the bat other than building it via object keys or some similar method, and without a JS function that does that directly, there can't be any TS way to get those values because TS only gives JS types and the latest ECMAScript standard.